# recvfrom fills the buffer with zeros

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I am trying to implement distance vector routing over udp.  I have the following structs:

```
struct cost_info { 
    uint8_t id; 
    uint8_t pad;
    uint16_t cost; 
}__attribute__((__packed__));

struct advertisement_packet { 
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t version;
    uint16_t num_updates;
    struct cost_info data[];
}__attribute__((__packed__));
```

So the packets are 1 byte type, 1 byte version, 2 bytes update count, and then 4*update count bytes of data.  I am using flexible array members so that I can just do

```
sendto(fd, pkt, sizeof(struct advertisement_packet) + pkt->num_updates * sizeof(struct cost_info), 0, addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

and send the entire thing in one packet.  Sending in one packet is required.
I am able to verify using wireshark that the data is being sent out correctly.  On the receiving end, I do two receives. The first gets the first 4 bytes so I can know how many updates to expect.  I then resize my receiver buffer accordingly and recieve 4*num_updates bytes.  The issue is that this second receive fills my buffer with zeros!  If I expect 12 bytes of data, I get 12 bytes of zeros.  The next time I read from that socket, I get the beginning of the next packet as expected.  Why would this happen?

Here is my receive code for if needed.

```
recvfrom(i, pkt, sizeof(struct advertisement_packet),0,NULL,0);
//reallocate more space if the incoming data will need it
if (pkt->num_updates > pkt_cost_slots) {
  pkt_cost_slots *= 2;
  pkt = realloc(pkt,sizeof(struct advertisement_packet) + sizeof(struct cost_info) * pkt_cost_slots);
  assert(pkt);
}
//receive data
recvfrom(i,pkt->data,pkt->num_updates * sizeof(struct cost_info),0,NULL,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot split receipt of one datagram over two `recv()` / `recvfrom()` calls.  It is the fundamental nature of datagram-oriented sockets that sends and receives operate in units of datagrams.  You can, however, read part or all of a datagram without removing it from the receive queue (i.e. "peek" at it).  [The specifications for `recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) put it this way:

> For message-based sockets, such as `SOCK_RAW`,
>   `SOCK_DGRAM`, and `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, the entire message shall
>   be read in a single operation. If a message is too long to fit in the
>   supplied buffer, and `MSG_PEEK` is not set in the flags argument, the
>   excess bytes shall be discarded.

You can thus accomplish your goal by using `MSG_PEEK` on the first `recvfrom()` call, but note that then you need to receive the *entire* datagram in the second `recvfrom()` call, not just the part that you did not read the first time.

Comment: Tried this.  I was able to get the size and then read the full amount the second time.  unfortunately, even though the second read said it got all 16 bytes, the data was sill zeroed out.

Comment: @Sandles, if you can verify on the receiving side, e.g. via wireshark, that the incoming data are structured as you expect, then my best guess is that the receiver has a different idea about the layout of `struct advertisement_packet` and / or `struct cost_info` than the sender does.  That could make it *appear* that the received data were all zeroes.  I suggest checking the actual data received by casting `pkt` to `unsigned char *` and going through it byte-by-byte.

Comment: Welp. I casted it and it most certainly is getting the data.  I still need to figure out why my struct access is returning 0, but I'm getting the data and that is what is important.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a datagram protocol. The entire datagram packet gets passed into the first `recvfrom` call.  If your buffer size is insufficient, then the data bytes will get lost. They are not passed to a subsequent `recvfrom`.

So the solution is to just pass in a buffer big enough for any UDP datagram and then cast it to your  data type.

```
unsigned char buffer[65535];
struct advertisement_packet *pkt = (advertisement_packet *)buffer;
recvfrom(i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);
```

Here's a better solution that also does the usual security checks so you don't get duped into a buffer overrun by a malicious attacker.

```
int result = 0;
unsigned char buffer[65535];
struct advertisement_packet *pkt = (advertisement_packet *)buffer;
sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
int accepted = false;

result = recvfrom(i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);

if (result > 0)
{
    size_t expected_size = sizeof(struct advertisement_packet) + pkt->num_updates * sizeof(struct cost_info);

    if (result >= expected_size)
    {
        accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // packet is malformed or undersized, so let's avoid a buffer overrun
        result = -1;
    }
}

if (accepted)
{
     // got packet and it's valid
     // continue parsing it, or make a copy of it.
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea as far as not having to reallocate memory.  However I just tried it and it did not fix the solution.  It received the expected 16 bytes  for my tests, and the first byte was still correct and the rest of the data was still zeroed out.